# Limiting DateTimePicker to folderstructure

Tags: c#

I have a folder structure looking like this:

- 2013

  - 08

    - 15
    - 16
    - 17
  - 10

    - 15
    - 16
    - 17

Is it possible to limit a DateTimePicker to only allow the user to select dates which are available in the folder structure?

Comment: Yes it is possible first you have to get the all the dates and create the list and then force user to select the dates from those list. OR after selecting  from datetimepicker validate against those lists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the calender in DateTimePicker control do not allow you to disable discrete dates

btw, setting the property `MinValue` and `MaxValue` in DateTimePicker can avoid user selecting dates before the `MinValue` and dates after `MaxValue`